# Hey im trying to run a script that checks if i installed everything right for my computer but im getting this error

Tags: bash

Hello im trying a run a script from my school to make sure i have everything installed correctly on my computer but im getting this error.

"It doesn't appear that your ~/.bashrc is running from either
your ~/.bash_profile or your ~/.profile files
This probably isn't what you want as non-login shells
Won't run your ~/.bashrc file

Here's an example of what you probably want in one
of your bash startup files

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
fi"
```

would really appreciate  some help.

Comment: check https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html

Comment: Use `[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ]` to ensure `.bashrc` is non-empty (you don't need to include an empty file) Fairly obvious the `'"'` following the closing `fi` is a typo. Paste your complete script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for excellent analysis.

Comment: yes sorry about the"".  im still having trouble understanding how to fix this. i typed in the above command you replied with and still nothing. thanks for your reply